# Managing duplicated lines across files

Tags: debian, text-processing, sort, cat, uniq

I am generating all the common/duplicate lines between 5 files all within the same directory

```
sort *.txt | uniq -d > output.txt
```

I need `output.txt` to be merged with File1.txt (so anything that isn't a duplicate is added) however elsewhere, in File2.txt if the duplicate line appears it needs to be removed.

Any pointers? Using Debian

**EDIT:** Merging output with File1 is easy as

```
cat output.txt >> File1.txt
```

then just removing the duplicates after with a regular expression.

Comment: Is the order of the lines in the output of any importance?

Comment: Can you add an example please ?

Comment: @Kusalananda No, it isnt.

Comment: @MhdWissamAl-Roujoulah In file 1 if anything is within output.txt that is additional and not a duplicate gets added. Yet in file 2 if a duplicate line from output.txt appears it is removed. These files are in different locations

Comment: James is still not clear. You can append something to any file with the use of `>>`. You can print and search for duplicates for multiple files with simple cat : `cat 'output.txt' 'file1' 'file2' '*.txt'  |uniq >> newoutput.file`. Is that simple ? I suppose is more complicated. Better to try to include samples in order we can work out a solution.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou No, it isn't that simple as File1.txt (what I wish to add too) already exists. If a line within output.txt matches a line within File1.txt it is ignored, however anything additional is added to File1. However if the line appears in File2, it is removed.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou To be fair, could just cat output.txt >> File1.txt then remove any duplicates afterwards. However this is still only half the issue, I need to remove the same information from File2.txt

Comment: @JamesBerrisford Please update the question with all the relevant information.

Comment: BTW You can send the output to both files using `cat output.txt |tee -a file1.txt file2.txt` . tee -a stands for append, similar to `>>` and as a bonus output.txt will be also printed in screen (this is what tee does....)

Comment: Or you can work file1 and file2 separately like `cat output.txt file1.txt |uniq >file1.txt` (the same file you cat in the beginning), and similar cat for output and file2.txt

Comment: Although it would be similar for file2 with cat @GeorgeVasiliou however it is removing, not appending.

Comment: The point is to first print the data of both files, keep or remove duplicates upon your needs (can be controlled by the uniq options) and re-write the "manipulated" data to the file1 (with single > to overwrite previous data). In other words, cat - manipulate - and write back to the same file.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Is this still applicable to removing?

Comment: Uniq alone (no switches) will remove duplicate lines. This is what uniq is used for. Cat will print all lines (output and file) pipe to Uniq that will keep unique lines (using just uniq) or will keep duplicate lines (uniq -d). The final result (i.e using uniq = duplicate lines removed) will be sent back to file1.txt overwritting it. Give it a try.

Comment: One momment to check something.

Comment: Forget it . Cat can not write on the same file used as input. We have to find another way

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou cat output.txt File2 | uniq -d > File2 overwrites File2 with the duplicate lines, I want it to remove those lines instead of writing them.

Comment: The output of d.txt is output.txt at the top of File.txt, it is not removing the duplicates. I need anything that appears in both files removed from File.txt  (File2) @GeorgeVasiliou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cat both files (output and file1.txt) then find uniq lines using just uniq (no switces) and finally write the result back to file1.txt

Example:

```
$ cat output.txt
Line1
$ cat file1.txt
Line1
Line3
Line4
$ echo "$(cat output.txt file1.txt |sort |uniq)" >file1.txt
$ cat file1.txt
Line1
Line3
Line4
```

If you want "Line1" to be completelly removed and not kept even once, then use uniq -u.

```
$ echo "$(cat output.txt file1.txt |sort |uniq -u)" >file1.txt && cat file1.txt
Line3
Line4
```

Similar operation for your file2.

PS: You can not cat and write on the same file at one operation. 
You have either to use the `echo $(...)` trick above or send the `cat |uniq` output to another file (temp file) and then either rename tempfile to file1 (`mv tempfile file1.txt`) or `cat tmpfile >file1.txt && rm tmpfile`.

Another solution would be to append output.txt to file1.txt (`cat output.txt >>file1.txt`) and use `sed -i` for removing the duplicate lines

Comment: sed -i File2.txt isn't removing duplicate lines

Comment: @JamesBerrisford No , sed will need a regex to remove duplicate lines, does not work like this. Also it might require file to be sorted first. See this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444406/how-can-i-delete-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-in-unix . Solution other than sed which supports inplace / in file replacements (`-i` switch) also might have the restriction that output file can not be the same as input file.

Comment: @JamesBerrisford also my solution requires sort. I will update my answer to be accurate and correct.